# how to work with not hidden? links in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I've hidden some of my links in my complete directed weighted graph, and I have a list (max-links) which gives the maximum out-link of every turtle and now I basically want to update max-links by telling it to show the maximum out-link of only (not hidden?) links

```
 set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles
```

I tried adding this at the end of the code

> of links with [not hidden?]

but it didn't work
how can I do this?
thanks

Comment: Please revisit how to ask a question. (1) What does "didn't work" mean? Error message - if so, what? Wrong behaviour - if so, what did it do and why is that wrong? (2) You are asking us to guess what your code looks like. Show us the code, not a statement about how you modified it. You can't have simply done `... [label]] of turtles of links with ...` because that makes no sense.

Comment: "didn't work" means a wrong behavior in other words nothing new happened after the modification.  (it still showed the hidden link in the list) and the modification was : 
max-links [ sort-on... of turtles] of links with [not hidden?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two places where you could eliminate hidden out-links. the first is to get them out of the way at the first stage of the process and then to find the maximum among only those that are not hidden.

```
set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of (my-out-links with [not hidden?]) [label]] of turtles
```

On the other hand, perhaps you want to identify the maximum links first and then get rid of those maximum links that are hidden.  In which case

```
set max-links sort-on [(- label)] (link-set [max-one-of my-out-links [label]] of turtles) with [not hidden?]
```